# Android fill path of arc is on wrong side

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, path

I have a path that is a serie of arc with first arc clockwise, next arc 
is counterclockwise, etc.... The last arc join the first in a circle way.

Somthing like this:

(

)

(

)

(

But in circle and each arc touch perfectly the next.

When i use fill, it fill only aproximately the half part of each circle, like if i stoke a line between the start and end point of each circle. The filled part is internal to every arc.

What i want is to fill the inner part of this shape composed of all this arc. Is there some params i have miss ?

Some code:

```
Path path = new Path();

// for simplicity let's say i have a couple of 
path.addArc(rect, (float)startingAngle, sweepAngle);

Paint paintPath = new Paint();
paintPath.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
paintPath.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getMeasuredWidth(), this.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
canvas.drawPath(path, paintPath);


canvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, paintPath);

imageViewackground.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
path.arcTo(rect, (float)startingAngle, sweepAngle);
```

or

```
path.arcTo(rect, (float)startingAngle, sweepAngle,true);
```

Comment: Omg, i was fighting for so long time with this little error. Thanks a lot !